# cin >> double cycling through loop when string is entered

Tags: c++, for-loop, cin

Sorry for this extreme noob question,

I am using a for loop with 5 iterations.  Each time it loops I prompt the user to enter a decimal, I use cin >> aDouble.  If I type in any number it works fine, but if I type in a string it will loop the five times, then go on.

Here's my code.

```
for(int i = 0; i <= ARRSIZE; i++)
{
    cout << "Please enter a decimal value: ";
    cin >> myDouble;

    if (!cin.fail() )
    {
        myVector.push_back(myDouble);
    }
}
```

Thank you!!

Comment: how did you declared your string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once a stream failed to read a value it sets `std::ios_base::failbit` and this bit stays set until it gets cleared. While an error bit is set, the stream doesn't do anything. That is, if `cin.fail()` is `true` you deal with the problem as well: You need to get rid of the "string":

```
if (std::cin.fail()) {
    std::cin.clear();
    std::cin.ignore();                                  // ignore one character or ....
    std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n'); // rest of line
}
```

Comment: Vielen Dank fuer die sehr spezifische Antwort Dieter!

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `cin.clear()` to clear the error state.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I put cin.clear() after my if statement, and it still loops if I enter a string.

Comment: `clear()`ing the stream make it operational again. However, it doesn't remove the "bad" characters. You need to get rid of them.